# How to backup/mirror/replicate remote git repo to another remote repo

Tags: git

We have a repo A hosted at http://github.com/A.git.

What I want is create a new repo http://github.com/B.git, then copy all contents from A.git to B.git, including all branches and tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a git plugin [git-copy](https://github.com/cybertk/git-copy) to achieve this goal easier. With the following commands

```
gem install git-copy
git copy http://github.com/A.git http://github.com/B.git
```

Comment: briefly looked at the code. should it use `git clone --mirror` instead of `git clone --bare` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add new remove repo with:

```
git remote add new_remote_repo git://github.com/B.git
```

And push there:

```
# push all branches
git push new_remote_repo --all
# push all tags
git push new_remote_repo --tags
```

Comment: Or `git push --mirror new_remote_repo`.

Comment: This will not push any branch to B.git, only tags copied